# KitaroDB on Surface

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, nosql

I'm using KitaroDB which is a NoSQL database provider on Windows RT. I use this piece of code to create the database:

```
private static readonly string _dbPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\MyKitaroDB.ism";
public async Task CreateT()
        {
            try
            {
                _db = await DB.CreateAsync(_dbPath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
        }
```

This code runs flawlessly on PC, but on surface tablet I catch an error `HRESULT : 0x8007007E`. I was wondering what was wrong in my code and if I am missing something. I know not many people use KitaroDB but maybe the mistake is a general one. I noticed that the library is compiled for x86 architecture so my project has to be compiled for that too ; may that be the reason I get the error?

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: By "Surface Tablet" do you mean Surface RT? That would require an ARM compiled image not x86, and the result code would typically mean a file/module wasn't found.  That said an x86 image shouldn't even run on RT. You're swallowing the exception in the empty catch clause by the way, so check out the stack trace and that may help diagnose.

Comment: It is a StoreApp. I referenced the KitaroDB SDK, not the DLL. It runs well when the application is released, I only get the error when I run it in debug mode. In my project, I referenced a winmd file so maybe when deploying to the device the dll file did not come along?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are running into a manifestation of the problem mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982667/extension-sdk-for-windows-8-store-apps-doesnt-work-during-remote-debugging).